# Como hacer para eliminar un registro a través de un modal

Tags: php, html

Tengo una lista de usuarios y cuando quiero eliminar un registro me sale un modal que va a permitir confirmar si el usuario quiere o no eliminar el usuario, cuando el usuario dice que si este elimina pero el primer registro de la lista aun cuando le estoy dando a eliminar al numero 3 o 4 de la lista, alguna idea de porque esto pase, aqui les dejo el codigo

Este es el html

```
<form method="post" id="f" action="delete_user.php?id=<?php echo (int)$a_user['id'];?>">
  <button type="button" id="deleteuser" name="deleteuser" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteuser"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button> 
</form>
```

El script que uso para que se elimine desde el modal es el siguiente

```
$("#modalDe").click(function() {
  $("#f").submit();
});
```

y mi funcion php para eliminar es esta

```
<?php
  $delete_id = delete_by_id('users',(int)$_GET['id']);
  if($delete_id){
   $session->msg("s","Usuario eliminado");
   redirect('users.php');
  } else {
   $session->msg("d","Se ha producido un error en la eliminación del usuario");
   redirect('users.php');
  }
?>
```

Y este es el codigo del modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteuser" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">¿Esta seguro que desea eliminar el usuario?</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="modalDe" name="modalDe" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar Usuario</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Testeaste el sql?

Comment: Si, ya logre resolver el problema, cambie la etiqeuta button por una etiqueta a y mediante jquery cree el modal y ahora si me elimina el registro que quiero eliminar

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, podrías compartirme tu solución?
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es por que no se ejecuta el submit, cambia el id del jquery que ejecuta el evento click.

```
$("#deleteuser").click(function() {
  $("#f").submit();
});
```

Comment: Hice este cambio y aun me sigue eliminando el primer registro de la lista

Comment: y el action? como te lo imprime (velo desde el navegador)

Comment: El action lo esta imprimiendo bien por ejemplo para el id 29 sale <form method="post" id="f" action="delete_user.php?id=29">